# rowdeselect event can't fire to save data when it is in last row in Extjs EditorGridPanel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using EditorGridPanel with cellEditor which acts nearly like Excel. We implemented Arrow Keys to move among rows and
columns. We do row validation when user moves from one row to another (specifically in rowdeselect event) and then save the
record. There is some issues are:

1. For the last row of the grid, rowdeselect event does not fire, as we do not have any other control after the grid.
2. rowdeselect event fires if we move from row to row using Tab, Enter & Arrow keys. But when user clicks on another row using mouse - events do not come in correct sequence, so focus moves to the new row, but earlier row not saved. Currently we solved this by calling stopEditing at the beginning of rowdeselect event.

We would like to know how we can solve these two issues and whether there are more robust ways to handle automatic grid saving.

You can fill free to check the problem in our site. -> http://www.softworksbd.com/swazilandlmis/yyyy_stockdata.php

Answer (score 0):

1 ) First of all the event is not firing on the blur of the whole grid and not just the last row. try changing a row and clicking anywhere on the screen but the grid and you will see that no validation takes place (which means your rowdselect does not fire).
You should try and add a blue event to the whole grid that runs your validation scripts.

2) As far as I have checked the event is fired even on another row click so please explain exactly what you mean...

ps

I have viewed only this page in your application:
[image]

Comment: Suppose my valid equation is: Opening+Receive+AdjustQty-Closing=DispenseQty. If I insert 0+1200+0-1000=200 and press Enter key it will be saved and dirty flag will disappear. But when this input is in last row of grid and i press Enter button it will not fire and also if i click any control outside of grid this event also not fire.

Comment: have you tried the 'selectionchange' event in the selection module ?